# Comparing in an Array: If two highest value exists, then compare the other value

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array like:

```
array( [0] => array([item]=>apple [buy]=>50 [sell]=>30)
       [1] => array([item]=>lemon [buy]=>50 [sell]=>60)
       [2] => array([item]=>banana [buy]=>40 [sell]=>20)
       [3] => array([item]=>orange [buy]=>20 [sell]=>30)
     )
```

Currently I am using this script to check which item has the most buyer

```
function getMax($array, $val)
{
   $max = 0;
   foreach( $array as $k => $v )
   {
      $max = max( array( $max, $v[$val] ) );
   }
   return $max;
}
$highestBuy = getMax($thisArray, 'buy');

foreach($thisArray as $i=>element){
    if($element['buy'] == $highestBuy){
        $thisArray[$i]['highestBuy'] = 'yes';
    } else {
        $thisArray[$i]['highestBuy'] = 'no';
    }
}
```

In this case, both `apple` and `lemon` will have `highestBuy` a `yes` value. But now I want to find out which item is the most popular by checking their `sell` if there are two or more same value of `highestBuy`. Which is the most simple or fastest way to make the output like:

```
array([0] => array([item]=>apple [buy]=>50 [sell]=>30 [mostPopular]=>no)
      [1] => array([item]=>lemon [buy]=>50 [sell]=>60 [mostPopular]=>yes)
      [2] => array([item]=>banana [buy]=>40 [sell]=>20 [mostPopular]=>no)
      [3] => array([item]=>orange [buy]=>20 [sell]=>30 [mostPopular]=>no)
     )
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

What I want to do is:

1. find out the highest `buy`
2. If this value occur only once(which means there are one highest `buy` in the array) then push the `[mostPouplar]=>yes` into the array
3. If not(there are two or more same highest value), then find out the highest `sell`.

That's mean if the highest value is unique, it will stop doing further action. If not, it will keep going to find secondary highest value in an array. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort array with your rules  and take first element

```
$array = array( '0' => array('item'=>apple, 'buy'=>50 ,'sell'=>30),
       '1' => array('item'=>lemon, 'buy'=>50, 'sell'=>60),
       '2' => array('item'=>banana, 'buy'=>40, 'sell'=>20),
       '3' => array('item'=>orange, 'buy'=>20 ,'sell'=>30)
     );     

usort($array,
    function($a, $b) {
       $res = $b['buy'] - $a['buy'];
       if (!$res) $res = $b['sell'] - $a['sell'];
       return $res; });
```

result:

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [item] => lemon [buy] => 50 [sell] => 60 )
[1] => Array ( [item] => apple [buy] => 50 [sell] => 30 )
[2] => Array ( [item] => banana [buy] => 40 [sell] => 20 )
[3] => Array ( [item] => orange [buy] => 20 [sell] => 30 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the `getMax()` to return the index of the most popular item

```
function getMax($array, $val, $val2)
{
   $max_item = 0;
   foreach( $array as $k => $v )
   {
      if($array[$max_item][$val] <= $v[$val] && $array[$max_item][$val2] <= $v[$val2])
        $max_item = $k;
   }
   return $max_item;
}

$highestBuy = getMax($thisArray, 'buy', 'sell');

foreach($thisArray as $i => $element){
    $thisArray[$i]['mostPopular'] = ($i == $highestBuy) ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```

Comment: your code seems get something wrong. It returned `banana` as most popular. Or did I missed something? [Example Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AxJuos).